# About android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, xml

I write a sample to learn BroadcastReceiver..But When I reboot my phone, the app broke down. Here is my source code and manifest.xml:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Toast.makeText(context,"Boot Complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
    }
  }
```

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.boot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>        
      <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

          </intent-filter>           
      </receiver>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a class named `com.example.boot.BootCompleteReceiver`, at least based on the code that you have shown in your answer.

While you have a class named `BootCompleteReceiver`:

- It is an inner class of `MainActivity`, and so `BootCompleteReceiver` is not named `com.example.boot.BootCompleteReceiver`
- It is a regular inner class of `MainActivity` (no `static` keyword), and so Android could not create an instance of it anyway, even if you had the right name in the manifest

Either move `BootCompleteReceiver` to be a regular standalone Java class in its own `.java` file, or make it be a `public static class` inside `MainActivity`. In the latter case, the fully-qualified class name for your manifest entry would be `com.example.boot.MainActivity$BootCompleteReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks..I see...I just copy the codes from a book..so it reported error..